# "Conversion to Swift 5 is available" Not able to convert code

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I'm trying to convert code to current swift version, but it is giving me issues. The steps I followed to convert code is

First I tried to convert using Edit->Convert->To Current Swift version

But at the end **it gives issues Use of undeclared type 'CWUITableViewController', Method does not override any method from its superclass, Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)'**

I have changed the swift version in build settings to Swift 5 and
**Code is compiling and running**

But when I tried to use the "To Current Swift version" option it fails at the end and gives unreasonable issues like "Use of undeclared type 'CWUITableViewController'"

and in the warning it still gives an option of "Conversion to Swift 5 is available"

**As the code is running using the Swift 5 compiler, so I guess code is converted to swift ?**

**Why it is giving showing warning "Conversion to Swift 5 is available" and giving issue "Use of undeclared type 'CWUITableViewController'" when tries to convert code ?**

Comment: Is CWUITableViewController your class?

Comment: yes it is a class that is inharited with UITableViewController and contain some common functions

Comment: Maybe you could add the code for the method that generates the error to your question?

Comment: if this "CWUITableViewController" is yours then you need to look into it. If its from a component of used any pod, then you need to wait until that particular component code is updated.

Answer (score 0):

if this "CWUITableViewController" is yours then you need to look into it. If its from a component of used any pod, then you need to wait until that particular component code is updated